# How can I return the parent using selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net

How do I return the parent element at specific index using only jQuery selector? to get by index I managed by using `:eq()` but `:parent` doesn't seem to work. It return the same element, regardless how many `:parent` I have. I've tried this:

```
div.unread span.text:eq(2):parent
```

The reason I need this is I'm writing a tool that target jQuery, it's because I'm using a .NET's browser that I must use Javascript to interact with the web page's DOM. Generate `.parent()` method would make the code generation a bit more complex. So I'm trying to make it short as possible, generating the selector make all the job, as possible.
So don't really worry if it's going to be unreadable, it's not going to be read by any human anyway.

Comment: Do not believe it is possible to select parent element using `css` selectors alone. Though you could extend jQuery to proivide that functionality.

Comment: How would be that extension? creating a new method for jQuery object? I'd like to do it using selector only to avoid make the code generator complex

Comment: Is the parent element of `span.text:eq(2)` an element other than `div.unread`? Can you include `html` and describe element expected to be matched at Question?

Answer (score 2):

You could extend jQuery expression to use your own one if you need the index of element to work globally:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    parentOf: function(elm, _, a) {
        return $(elm).find($(a[3])).length
    }
});
```

Then use:

```
$('div.unread:parentOf(span.text:eq(2))')
```

```js
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    parentOf: function(elm, _, a) {
        return $(elm).find($(a[3])).length
    }
});


$('div.unread:parentOf(span.text:eq(2))').css('color', 'red');
$('span.text:eq(2)').css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="unread">
  <span class="text">span</span>
  <span class="text">span</span>
  <span class="text">span</span>
</div>
<div class="unread">
  <span class="text">span</span>
  <span class="text">span</span>
  <span class="text">span</span>
</div>
<div class="unread">
  <span class="text">span</span>
  <span class="text">span</span>
  <span class="text">span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @guest271314 Because on DOM there is only one `span:eq(2)`. I was guessing it to be your expected behaviour, otherwise use Rory's answer. UPDATE: see how works `:eq()`: https://jsfiddle.net/1j9r7801/

Comment: Each `div.unread` contains a `span:eq(2)` descendant element?

Comment: No, only first `div`. Again see which is the `div.unread span:eq(2)` in jsFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/1j9r7801/  Otherwise, it would be `:nth-child(3)`. I know, it is quite confusing...

Comment: This is approach was attempting to describe to OP. Yes, the default return value of `:eq()` is a single element; though with multiple `div.unread` parent elements and selector `:parentOf(span.text:eq(2))`, here, would expect multiple matches of `div.unread` to be returned, as each `div.unread` element contains a descendant element that matches `span.text:eq(2)` selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:has` selector to retrieve a parent based on it's children:

```
$('div.unread:has(span.text:eq(2))');
```

Note that as noted by @A.Wolff, the `:eq()` selector in this instance works in the context of each individual `div.unread` element, not globally, if that was your original intent.

Comment: `:eq()` won't match global element index but child one if used in `:has()`, i don't know why?! EDIT: i guess this is expected behaviour because `:has()` will check only for descendants, so, any selector passed there will target **only** children...  See what i mean [here](https://jsfiddle.net/86wr0ac0/)

Comment: @A.Wolff very good point. I'll update to include a note about that and a fix using `:nth-child()`: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/86wr0ac0/1/

Comment: Sorry but this is the opposite: `:eq() selector in this instance works globally` No it works on children only

Comment: Pretty sure it's global - that's why in your first example only one span is coloured green.

Comment: But the 3 divs are red, while only the one containing the third `span` should be. (the green span)

Comment: Although in testing, both seem to work fine in the OPs case: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pzLbv669/

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Re-reading the Question, it could be that `span.text:eq(2)` is child of an element within `div.unread`, and OP is expecting that parent element to be matched? Else, what is point of selector `div.unread span.text:eq(2)` only to return `div.unread`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest()` which denotes parent in jQuery

```
$('span.text:eq(2)').closest('div.unread');
```

You can also use like

```
$('span.text:eq(2)').closest('div.unread').css("background","red");

$('span.text').eq(2).closest('div.unread').css("background","green");

$('span.text:nth-child(2)').closest('div.unread').css("background","blue");


$('span.text:nth-child(3)').parents('div.unread').css("background","orange");
//:nth-child(3) denotes 3rd element unlike eq(3) refers 4th element

$('span.text:nth-child(3)').parent().css("background","yellow");
```

```js
$('span.text:eq(2)').closest('div.unread').css("background","red");

$('span.text').eq(2).closest('div.unread').css("background","green");

$('span.text:nth-child(2)').closest('div.unread').css("background","blue");


$('span.text:nth-child(3)').parents('div.unread').css("background","orange");

$('span.text:nth-child(3)').parent().css("background","yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="unread">
  <span class="text">text1</span>
  <span class="text">text2</span>
  <span class="text">text3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: _How do I return the parent element at specific index **using only jQuery selector**_